# How do I center a background image in my email header?

Tags: html, css, background-image, image-resizing

I'm working on an HTML email and I'm running into a few blockers. I can't figure out how to center the image header or how to change the opacity of the background image.

I've tried multiple different class movements and dabbled with the CSS but to no success. I've attached a mockup of how it should look (the height should be desktop height)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>NASCAR Fan Email</title>
  <style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
      table.body h1 {
        font-size: 28px !important;
        margin-bottom: 10px !important;
      }
      table.body p,
      table.body ul,
      table.body ol,
      table.body td,
      table.body span,
      table.body a {
        font-size: 16px !important;
      }
      table.body .wrapper,
      table.body .article {
        padding: 10px !important;
      }
      table.body .content {
        padding: 0 !important;
      }
      table.body .container {
        padding: 0 !important;
        width: 100% !important;
      }
      table.body .main {
        border-left-width: 0 !important;
        border-radius: 0 !important;
        border-right-width: 0 !important;
      }
      table.body .img-responsive {
        height: auto !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
        width: auto !important;
      }
    }
    
    @media all {
      .ExternalClass {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .ExternalClass,
      .ExternalClass p,
      .ExternalClass span,
      .ExternalClass font,
      .ExternalClass td,
      .ExternalClass div {
        line-height: 100%;
      }
      .apple-link a {
        color: inherit !important;
        font-family: inherit !important;
        font-size: inherit !important;
        font-weight: inherit !important;
        line-height: inherit !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
      }
      #MessageViewBody a {
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-weight: inherit;
        line-height: inherit;
      }
      .btn-primary table td:hover {
        background-color: #34495e !important;
      }
      .btn-primary a:hover {
        background-color: #34495e !important;
        border-color: #34495e !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style=" font-family: sans-serif; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; line-height: 2.4; margin: 0; padding: 0; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
  <span class="imageheader" style="color: transparent; display: none; height: 0; max-height: 0; max-width: 0; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all; visibility: hidden; width: 0;">This
        is preheader text. Some clients will show this text as a preview.</span>
  <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%;" width="100%" bgcolor="#f6f6f6">
    <tr>
      <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="container" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; display: block; max-width: 800px; padding: 10px; width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;" width="800" valign="top">
        <div class="content" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: block; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 800px; padding: 10px;">

          <!-- START CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
          <table style="background-image: url('https://www.nascar.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2022/01/07/NFC_Horiz_BlackRGB.png'); width: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px; border-bottom: 10px solid red;" width="100%">
            <table role="presentation" class="main" style="background-image: url('https://www.nascar.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2022/01/07/NASCAR_FanCouncil_DaytonaFanPhoto_1-1.jpg'); width: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; padding: 60px;" width="100%">

              <!-- START MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
              <tr>
                <td class="wrapper" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px;" valign="top">
                  <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%;" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                          Hello,</p>
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                          We’d like to invite you to participate in a short survey about this past weekend’s races. This survey should take less than 5 minutes and will be open through Wednesday, August 25. We want to know what you think!</p>
                        <p class="targetlink">
                          <!-- <a class="targetlink" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 15px; text-transform: uppercase;" href="http://www.nascarfancouncil.com/c/al/5YVqVGmxA5g98218UalK-Bl/5bn1vdLmXO68WPcydpyM7J">Click here to start</a></p> -->
                          <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                            If you are unable to click the link, please copy and past the full URL below into your browser:</p>
                          <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 15px;" valign="top">
                                  <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: auto;">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <a class="targetlink" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 15px; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.nascarfancouncil.com/c/al/5YVqVGmxA5g98218UalK-Bl/5bn1vdLmXO68WPcydpyM7J">Click here to start</a>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                            This is a really simple email template. Its sole purpose is to get the recipient to click the button with no distractions.</p>
                          <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                            Good luck! Hope it works.</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>

              <!-- END MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
            </table>
            <!-- END CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->



        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't use opacity or background image on emails html. While it may work on many clients as gmail it won't work on others as... Outlook. Yes, it's is a disgrace but microsoft don't give a fuck about it... which, after so many years, still angers me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have background images in emails with text on top, here is why:

First of all to center the background you can use (see snippet)

```
background-position: center center;
```

and to add opacity you can do things like

```
opacity:0.5
```

or

```
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
```

Although none of the previous will work on a background, you would need to add it as an image and then position it absoulute behinde the text. And here comes the greatest problem.

Emails are a complicated things to code because of compatibilty issues, for instance, your css styles might not work because some email clients are not compatible with `<style>`, as well as media queries, or even styles like `opacity`.

It is recommended that all CSS is inline and work strictly with tables, (which you already do, great!). But when it comes to images, images must be as `<img/>` and not css `background`, because many email clients will not show the image, and that's why you can't have text on top of them. It is true that you can use position absolute as I said before, but css positining is not compatible with emals.

That's why, see all the promotional emails that you get and none of them uses background images.

Another tip: make sure your html has no errors, or many email clients like gmail will consider it as spam. For instance I noticed that you have a `<table>` followed by another `<table>`, when you must have `<table><tr></td>` or `<th>` and then another `<table>` (also don't foget of `<tbody>` )

I found a great comaptibility gude:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Good luck!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>NASCAR Fan Email</title>
  <style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
      table.body h1 {
        font-size: 28px !important;
        margin-bottom: 10px !important;
      }
      table.body p,
      table.body ul,
      table.body ol,
      table.body td,
      table.body span,
      table.body a {
        font-size: 16px !important;
      }
      table.body .wrapper,
      table.body .article {
        padding: 10px !important;
      }
      table.body .content {
        padding: 0 !important;
      }
      table.body .container {
        padding: 0 !important;
        width: 100% !important;
      }
      table.body .main {
        border-left-width: 0 !important;
        border-radius: 0 !important;
        border-right-width: 0 !important;
      }
      table.body .img-responsive {
        height: auto !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
        width: auto !important;
      }
    }
    
    @media all {
      .ExternalClass {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .ExternalClass,
      .ExternalClass p,
      .ExternalClass span,
      .ExternalClass font,
      .ExternalClass td,
      .ExternalClass div {
        line-height: 100%;
      }
      .apple-link a {
        color: inherit !important;
        font-family: inherit !important;
        font-size: inherit !important;
        font-weight: inherit !important;
        line-height: inherit !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
      }
      #MessageViewBody a {
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-weight: inherit;
        line-height: inherit;
      }
      .btn-primary table td:hover {
        background-color: #34495e !important;
      }
      .btn-primary a:hover {
        background-color: #34495e !important;
        border-color: #34495e !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style=" font-family: sans-serif; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; line-height: 2.4; margin: 0; padding: 0; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
  <span class="imageheader" style="color: transparent; display: none; height: 0; max-height: 0; max-width: 0; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all; visibility: hidden; width: 0;">This
        is preheader text. Some clients will show this text as a preview.</span>
  <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%;" width="100%" bgcolor="#f6f6f6">
    <tr>
      <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="container" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; display: block; max-width: 800px; padding: 10px; width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;" width="800" valign="top">
        <div class="content" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: block; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 800px; padding: 10px;">

          <!-- START CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
          <table style="background-image: url('https://www.nascar.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2022/01/07/NFC_Horiz_BlackRGB.png'); width: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px; border-bottom: 10px solid red; background-position: center center;" width="100%">
            <table role="presentation" class="main" style="background-image: url('https://www.nascar.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2022/01/07/NASCAR_FanCouncil_DaytonaFanPhoto_1-1.jpg'); width: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; padding: 60px;" width="100%">

              <!-- START MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
              <tr>
                <td class="wrapper" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px;" valign="top">
                  <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 100%;" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                          Hello,</p>
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                          We’d like to invite you to participate in a short survey about this past weekend’s races. This survey should take less than 5 minutes and will be open through Wednesday, August 25. We want to know what you think!</p>
                        <p class="targetlink">
                          <!-- <a class="targetlink" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 15px; text-transform: uppercase;" href="http://www.nascarfancouncil.com/c/al/5YVqVGmxA5g98218UalK-Bl/5bn1vdLmXO68WPcydpyM7J">Click here to start</a></p> -->
                          <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                            If you are unable to click the link, please copy and past the full URL below into your browser:</p>
                          <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 15px;" valign="top">
                                  <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: auto;">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <a class="targetlink" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 15px; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.nascarfancouncil.com/c/al/5YVqVGmxA5g98218UalK-Bl/5bn1vdLmXO68WPcydpyM7J">Click here to start</a>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                            This is a really simple email template. Its sole purpose is to get the recipient to click the button with no distractions.</p>
                          <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                            Good luck! Hope it works.</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>

              <!-- END MAIN CONTENT AREA -->
            </table>
            <!-- END CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->



        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```